# Login form not recognising that the submit button has been clicked

Tags: html, forms, authentication

I've created a login form that's set up to query a database and search through it to see if what's typed in matches any users/passwords in the database. I've put echo's into my loginsubmit.php and it echos before the submit but not after. Here is my loginform.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
include 'connection.php';
include 'loginsubmit.php';


?>


<body> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
</head>
<p><font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<div id="loginform">

<center>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Please enter your login details<br><br>
Username:<br>
<form method="post" action="loginsubmit.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="password">

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</font></p>
</center>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<style>
body {

        font-size: 14px;
       }
</style>
```

and my loginsubmit.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))

{

$user = $_POST['username'];
print($username);
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$user' && Password='$pass'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo "login submit page";
    }
        else    
        {
            echo 'Not a valid login';   
        }
}



?>


    <?php
    include 'connection.php';

    if (isset($_POST['Submit']))

    {

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    print($username);
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$user' && Password='$pass'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo "login submit page";
        }
            else    
            {
                echo 'Not a valid login';   
            }
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, beacuse you are include that before the form.

Comment: And you code is totally invalid.

Comment: I started teaching myself HTML yesterday mate so it's not going to be perfect haha!

Comment: In your HTML be sure to give the submit button the name of submit. Look at you first few lines in loginsubmit.php

Comment: Learn more HTML and css. Your code needs it. (I know since I taught myself coding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally wrong, in HTML and PHP side too. I will explain it later, just here is how should it to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Why this in not website.css??? -->
        <style>
            body {
                font-size: 14px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css" />
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div id="loginform" style="font-family: 'ClearSans-Thin'; color: lightgray">
        <center>
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        Please enter your login details<br /><br />
        Username:<br />
        <form method="post" action="loginsubmit.php">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="text" name="password" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </center>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the PHP file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    print($user);
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Users WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row["cnt"] > 0) {
        echo "login submit page";
    } else {
        echo 'Not a valid login';
    }
}
```

So the problems:

- HTML file is starting with DTD, then opening `html` then `head` `title` closing `</head>` `<body>` content, `</body>` and `</html>`. The `<style></style>`  goes to head section.
- You included too early the `loginsubmit.php`
- You were duplicated the content of your `loginsubmit.php`.
- You were used `$_POST["Submit"]` instead `$_POST["submit"]`
- You were mixed `HTML4` and `HTML5` codes.

Answer (score 0):

When a form is send from a action the key inside the $_POST array is the name of the input not the value

In your html you have your button :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And your Php is waiting for :

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) // Btw you forgot the openning { in this if
```

So if you want this PhP to work you need to add a name to the submit like so :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

Notice the lowercase on submit so if you copie this change the `$_POST['Submit']` to `$_POST['submit']`

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Why the downvote without any command this isn't productive/constructive?

Comment: Legend! That fixed it, however it seems to have a problem with the mysqli. I get the error 

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/loginsubmit.php on line 16
Not a valid login

Comment: It says its not a valid login, however the login credentials i enter are the same as the ones in the database

Comment: When you Print `$result` what is tthe output ?

Answer (score -1):

```
need to be like this:
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
then calls: $_POST['Submit']
```

Comment: I think i have pointed your wrong issue in here. If it did not solve your problem, it still pointed out your wrong code.